# What does it mean for an image to have a distribution?

Tags: machine-learning

While studying Independent Component Analysis, specifically SVD to be used for the task of image separation. The lines given in the textbook is like this:-

"The first assumption will be that the two images are statistically independent."

Now, Statistical independence means images must have some kind of distribution to start with. But I am unable to grasp the meaning behind this. What does it mean for an image to have a distribution? Like how is a image having Gaussian distribution or Uniform distribution look like. It would be great if some examples are presented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we must understand that an image can be represented as the numerical values of its pixels. For example, a 256x256 grayscale image can be represented by a vector of 65536 integer values between 0 and 255.

Now, let's consider that we are talking about images of human faces, like the [CelebA dataset](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html), but in grayscale.

And finally, let's imagine that we sample a vector of 65536 components from a uniform distribution between 0 and 255, that is, from $x \sim U[0, 255]^{65536}$. If we interpret such a randomly sampled vector as an image, like the interpretation we described in the first paragraph, do you think that is it probable that we see a face? Well, probably not. Probably we would see just noise, like this:

[image]

Why do you know that we won't see a face? Well, because you know that a face is not composed of uniformly random pixels, but has some structure in it. In other words, because you intuitively know that the distribution of pixel values of a face image does not match $U[0, 255]^{65536}$, but has a different distribution.

As a summary, the distribution of an image *domain* is the distribution the pixel values follow. Note that this is applicable not only to grayscale images, but to color images expressed in the [RGB space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space) or any other numeric space like [HSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

P.S.: this is how an image of Gaussian noise looks like (it was generated with [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/), with `convert -size 256x256 xc:gray +noise Gaussian out.png`):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on the issue. I suspected uniform distribution might look like this but I am not sure of an image whose distribution will be gaussian. Could you add examples for that in your answer too.

Comment: I edited the answer to add an image of Gaussian noise

Comment: Please, consider upvoting the answer if you found it useful, and marking it as correct if deemed so.

Comment: Thanks! it more or less looks like random only. I wonder how does this creates issues in ICA for images. I have read that for ICA the images are supposed to be non-Gaussian(it is at this moment I had doubt what a gaussian image would look like), otherwise the method is unable to identify the independent axes. Any clarification on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/97049/40048) may help you with the non-Gaussian requirement of Independent Component Analysis (ICA).